# Custom checksum algorithm in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

How can I make the following checksum algorithm more pythonic and readable?

```
items = {1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three'}
text = "foo" # This variable may change on runtime. Added to allow the execution
number = 1 # This variable may change on runtime. Added to allow the execution

string = text + items[number] + " " + "trailing"
if items[number] == "two": string=text
string = [ord(x) for x in string]
iterator = zip(string[1:], string)
checksum = string[0]
for counter, (x, y) in enumerate(iterator):
    if counter % 2:
        checksum += x
        checksum += 2 * y
    else:
        checksum += x * y
checksum %= 0x10000

print("Checksum:", checksum)
```

The thing called `salt` by everyone here is fixed and won't change ever. Also, the code is into a bigger function.

This code as-is must return this:

```
Checksum: 9167
```

Comment: I don't know how this got 3 up votes. The code **does not run** as it is. More, we don't have any context about what this code is supposed to do. Could you please edit your question and add more context / the extra piece of code you omitted ?

Comment: @Dex'ter: Sorry. This happens when you extract a code snippet and then generalize it with laziness. I neither know how does this have 3 up votes.

Comment: @Dex'ter Well, it ran for me when setting `str_a` and `str_b` to some strings ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, I would apply the ["Extract Method" refactoring method](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) and put the logic behind generating a checksum into a `get_checksum()` function.

Also, I would avoid hardcoding the `trailing` "salt" and the `0x10000` "normalizer" and put them into the default keyword argument value and to a "constant" respectively.

You can use `sum()` instead of having loop with if and else, which increase the overall nestedness. But, it might become less explicit and potentially a bit more difficult to understand.

Comments and docstrings would definitely be needed to describe the logic behind the checksum calculations.

Variable naming can be improved - `str_a`, `str_b` and `string` are not the best choices (even though the `part1` and `part2` in the code below are not either - think about what these strings represent - may be you'll come up with better variable names). Also, note that you are reusing the `string` variable to keep the "ords" of each character, which, strictly speaking, is not good - the variable name does not correspond to what it is used for.

At the end you would have something like:

```
DEFAULT_SALT = "trailing"
NORMALIZER = 0x10000


def get_checksum(part1, part2, salt=DEFAULT_SALT):
    """Returns a checksum of two strings."""

    combined_string = part1 + part2 + " " + salt if part2 != "***" else part1
    ords = [ord(x) for x in combined_string]

    checksum = ords[0]  # initial value

    # TODO: document the logic behind the checksum calculations
    iterator = zip(ords[1:], ords)
    checksum += sum(x + 2 * y if counter % 2 else x * y
                    for counter, (x, y) in enumerate(iterator))
    checksum %= NORMALIZER

    return checksum
```

We can see that the test you've mentioned in the question passes:

```
$ ipython3 -i test.py 
In [1]: get_checksum("foo", "one")
Out[1]: 9167
```

Comment: Can you update the answer with the new code? I've made a edit after the Dex' ter comment.

Comment: @Helio You can use his (and also my) function directly, even with your new code, by just passing it the correct arguments.

Comment: @Graipher: Yes. P. S: You made a typo on my nick**name**. **;-)**

Comment: @Helio Hah, it was not yet too late to fix it :)

Comment: `part1`becomes `name`, part2 will take one of these values `{1:'ver_one', 2:'', 3:'ver_three'}` and `salt` is ` version`. The "salt" can be constant. *;-)*

Comment: Would be sane to use a nested `def` for the calculations and call it from sum like this? `sum(calculations(x, y) for counter, (x, y) in enumerate(iterator))`. Is better as-is?

Comment: @Helio I don't think it would improve the readability much, but it would be much more expensive - especially on the bigger strings - you'll see the performance degradation. I think putting a comment/docstring describing what is happening in the loop should be good enough. But, of course, code reviewing and refactoring is a continuous process - we can also find things to improve here on codereview site :)

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I find it near to the perfection now!

Comment: @Helio sure, glad to help! By the way, you may also look into `PyPy` - if your code would perform better comparing to CPython - I've tried some benchmarks but got stuck on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095793/accurately-testing-pypy-vs-cpython-performance.

Comment: @alecxe: Wow! In my case PyPy or CPython is truly overkilling because I don't need efficiency. I won't do bruteforce attacks nor computing of large strings. :-) Sorry. I ca't help you on that question because I never done these things :-/

Answer (score 6):

Similarly to [alecxe's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/154724/98493), i would wrap the code in a function and make the salt a parameter.

I would use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) for building the `string` (and still use a ternary).

I see no need for the explicit `iterator` variable, just inline it.

```
def checksum(str_a, str_b, salt):
    string = str_a if str_b == "***" else "{}{} {}".format(str_a, str_b, salt)
    string = [ord(x) for x in string]
    checksum = string[0]
    for counter, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(string[1:], string)):
        if counter % 2:
            checksum += x + 2 * y
        else:
            checksum += x * y
    return checksum % 0x10000
```

Answer (score 5):

Okay so i did read this question few hours ago on phone and started working out an answer on paper, having the performance tag in mind.
So here it is:

untouched lines:

```
items = {1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three'}
text = "foo" # This variable may change on runtime. Added to allow the execution
number = 1 # This variable may change on runtime. Added to allow the execution
```

first changes made here. Your Code does set sring and overwrtes it if `items[numer]` equals string "two". I dont like those inline if elses in long lines so i will take more space then other answers but think this is more readable.

```
if items[number] == "two":
    string = text
else:
    string = "{}{} trailing".format(text, items[number])
```

next line is untouched again with:

```
string = [ord(x) for x in string]
```

and now my performance-part comes into play. To understand i will explain your algorith and how i rearanged it. You zip the String starting with the second element and itself. This resolves to `[[string[1], string[0]], [string[2], string[1]], ... , [string[last element], string[last element -1]]]`.
This is a list with len(string) -1 elements.

So we will memorize strings length

```
string_len = len(string)
```

We will also memorize if the number of zip-lists elements would be even or odd. In case string has an odd number of elements zip-list would have an even number and if strings number of elements would be even zip-lists had been odd.

```
odd = (string_len -1) % 2
```

We will also do the initial setup for checksum as is:

```
checksum = string[0]
```

Iterating over iterator there are 2 cases: the iteration is odd

> if counter % 2:
>          checksum += x
>          checksum += 2 * y

or its even

> else:
>          checksum += x * y

There are two things unnecessary in my opinion. First is creating the zip-list since you can access every element by index. Element x is `string[iteration+1]`, y is `string[iteration]`. Since counter is successively even and odd we can also say that for two iterations we will once do

> checksum += x * y
>   in case our iteration-counter is even and
>   checksum += x
>   checksum += 2 * y
>   in case its not even.

Or we will just allways do 2 iterations in one step and do both operations like:

```
for i in range(0, string_len -1 -odd, 2):
    checksum += string[i] * string[i + 1]  # counter % 2 := false checksum += x * y
    checksum += string[i + 2]  # counter % 2 := true checksum += x
    checksum += 2 * string[i + 1]  # counter % 2 := true checksum += 2 * y
```

Now why we did memorize if zip-lists number of elements would had been odd or even:
We allways made 2 operations but this wont work for an odd number of operations. So we will check **once** with an if what to do:

```
if odd:
    checksum += string[i] * string[i + 1]
```

Anything else as is:

```
checksum %= 0x10000
print("Checksum:", checksum)
```

it might be recommendable to save the modulo in another place like other answers mention.

Entire Code looks like this:

```
items = {1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three'}
text = "foo" # This variable may change on runtime. Added to allow the execution
number = 1 # This variable may change on runtime. Added to allow the execution

if items[number] == "two":
    string = text
else:
    string = str.format("{:s}{:s} trailing", text, items[number])

string = [ord(x) for x in string]

string_len = len(string)
odd = (string_len -1) % 2

checksum = string[0]

for i in range(0, string_len -1 -odd, 2):
    checksum += string[i] * string[i + 1]  # counter % 2 := false checksum += x * y
    checksum += string[i + 2]  # counter % 2 := true checksum += x
    checksum += 2 * string[i + 1]  # counter % 2 := true checksum += 2 * y

if odd:
    checksum += string[i] * string[i + 1]

checksum %= 0x10000
print("Checksum:", checksum)
```

Comment: Agree on the ternary being borderline too long to understand. Would write `string = "{}{} trailing".format(text, items[number])`, though as being shorter and just as easy to read IMO. Also, `:s` is implied.

Comment: You are absolutely right, somehow i didnt come up with the right method call. Especially this is more OOP which i like, will change it :)

Answer (score 4):

My review (Python 3).

```
items = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}
text = "foo"
number = 1

string_original = "{}{} trailing".format(text, items[number])

if items[number] == "two":
    string_original = text

ord_list = [ord(x) for x in string_original]
checksum = ord_list[0]

for i in range(1, len(ord_list)):
    x, y = ord_list[i], ord_list[i-1]

    # The `-1` is necessary since parity is changed by starting the loop on 1
    if (i-1) % 2:
        checksum = checksum + x + 2*y
    else:
        checksum = checksum + x*y

checksum %= 0x10000

print("Checksum:", checksum)
```

Some notes about it:

- I had recommend putting the code after an `if` statement on its own line, even if it is only a single statement.
- Always leave one space when declaring variables. `string = text` and not `str=text` (unless specifying default parameters inside a function).
- I had also recommend not use the `+=` kind of operators when there a is a non trivial expression on the right side, even though this might come down to personal preference.
- Also, you should try to avoid using generic names such as string for naming your variables.
- Regardless of the language used, always try to see if you can simplify the code somehow, in order to make it more maintainable.